Drop duplicated values of files in a folder based on two columns R
I have over 250 large .txt files (each approximately 1GB) in a folder. I would like to remove duplicated rows based on two columns of id1 and id2 being mindful of my Macbook's memory limitations.
An examples of the .txt files are as follows (each file has many more columns):
user_1<-structure(list(id1 = c(4860291, 4860291, 4860291, 1030170, 
1438568, 1592420, 1702541, 1852977, 2143816, 2677860, 2677860, 
2677860, 2677860, 2912792, 2939878, 3043611, 4357890, 4769884, 
3225376, 3225376, 2864095), country = c("Peru", "Peru", "Peru", 
"United States", "United States", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Netherlands"), id2 = c(393550, 393550, 
393550, 393529, 393529, 393529, 393529, 393529, 393529, 393529, 
393529, 393529, 393529, 393529, 393529, 393529, 393529, 393529, 
393530, 393530, 393533)), row.names = 2372162:2372182, class = "data.frame")
.
.
.
user_250<-structure(list(id1 = c(4860280, 4860280, 2090372, 2970838, 
3469113, 1081704, 2243163, 3840895, 4159060, 4198012, 1604125, 
3159686, 3159686, 3159686, 2020953, 3444818, 2346651, 3733232, 
4577578, 4779099, 1832738), country = c("United States", "United States", 
"India", "United States", "United States", "Australia", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "United States", "United States", 
"Australia", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"Germany"), id2 = c(674, 674, 675, 676, 679, 680, 682, 682, 
682, 682, 686, 686, 686, 686, 688, 688, 691, 694, 694, 694, 695
)), row.names = 1648773:1648793, class = "data.frame")
 

My understanding for doing this for single file is:
read.delim("myfilepath/user_1.txt")
user_1 [!duplicated(user_1[c(id1,id2)]),]

How should I apply this to all the 250 files above?

Why read.delim? Do those files have a special character as column delimiter?

Because I thought I need to use read.delim() to open .txt files. like when I use read.CSV for csv files. Is this wrong?

You can use read.table to read .txt files.

Something like this? Untested.
# one of these two patterns should get all user_*.txt files
patt <- "user_\\d+\\.txt"
# patt <- "\\.txt"
fname_vec <- list.files(path = "myfilepath", pattern = patt, full.names = TRUE)

lapply(fname_vec, \(fname) {
  df1 <- read.delim(fname)
  i <- !duplicated(df1[c("id1", "id2")])
  write.table(df1[i,], fname, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
})


Thank you. Is df1 one of the files in the folder?

@bear_525 No, it's a temporary data.frame that exists only in the anonymous function called by lapply. If you want to test the code above, start with something like lapply(fname_vec[1:2], etc). This will test the code in files only.

@bear_525 As for read.delim, if the files have column names maybe better is df1 <- read.table(fname, header = TRUE).

Thank you. So for me to see the results of the  lapply() do I need to assign it to something? In other words how can I see the results of this change of dropping the duplicates? Or are the files altered on the spot?

@bear_525 The files are read, altered and an altered version is rewritten to the very same files. If you want to keep the original files, the names in write.table should be changed (which is a simple thing to do). Since you mention memory concerns, the code does not return the changes, as a matter of fact, it returns NULL for each and every file.

Thank you. I just opened the files but they seem to be unaltered. I used both patts. I wonder if I have made a mistake somewhere. For example in "myfilepath" should it be the path to the folder or one of the files? In the question I have used the path to one of the files.

@bear_525 "myfilepath" is the path to the files. I have assumed they are all in the same directory. What does file.exists(fname_vec) return?

It returns TRUE TRUE... TRUE

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
